# Changed Development to Production Env Broke App

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am new to dotnet core.

I am building a Dotnet Core WebAPI app and everything was working fine under `Development` env but when I changed to `Production` in ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, the following Unhandled Exception occurred:

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalDatabase")));

\\ Error 
\\ System.ArgumentException: 'Option 'user variables' not supported.'
\\ This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
\\  [External Code]
 ReferralSystem.Startup.ConfigureServices.AnonymousMethod__0(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder) in Startup.cs
\\  [External Code]
```

What is the likely reason?

Comment: Are you using a different connection string for the Production environment? See https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/194

Comment: `everything was working fine under Development env but when I changed to Production in ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, the following Unhandled Exception occurred` Please double check the `appsettings.{Environment}.json` file and connection string, and you can know how `appsettings.{Environment}.json` works from this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#appsettingsjson

Answer (score 1):

You should check your `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Production.json`.

Development use `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.Development.json`.

Production use  `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.Production.json`.